# extra small line on popup menu android

Tags: android, popupmenu

I have a popup menu with 2-3 buttons, the thing is I get a small line (marked in yellow in the pic). there aren't any other buttons so it is not a part of the next button.

this is the menu code:

```
    holder.optionsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getContext(), v);

            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_post, popup.getMenu());
            if ((post.getPublisher() != null &&
                    post.getPublisher().equals(ExploreActivity.getUsername())) ||
                    (ProtestActivity.protest.getAdmin() != null &&
                            ProtestActivity.protest.getAdmin().equals(post.getPublisher()))){
                popup.getMenu().add("Delete");
                Log.v(TAG, "adding delete to menu");
            }else {
                Log.v(TAG, "publisher: " + post.getPublisher() + " username: " + ExploreActivity.getUsername());
            }
            popup.show();
        }
    });
```

and this is the menu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/sharePost"
        android:title="Share" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/reportPost"
        android:title="Report" />
</menu>
```

this is the styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="NoAnimTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

and styles.xml (v21)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    </style>
</resources>
```

[image: image of the problem here]

Comment: It is part of the delete item . not next item

Comment: Hi, none of the examples I've seen has this, in addition, there is not elevated shadow effect on the bottom of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding delete item in the menu along with two other items because each time you dynamically adding makes it complex and due to this the extra space is coming through.In your code just need to show and hide delete item which is already in menu.xml.

Comment: Did you try it on some other device ? because same code is working just fine on my device,

Comment: happens both on my OnePlus One and my Nexus 4

Comment: I ran same code and its working for me. can you show your style.xml ?